# call member C++ function but C function has same name

Tags: c++, c, function, namespaces, member

I am using a C libtrary with

```
#define read _io_read
```

but I have a C++ class which inherits a member function 'read'.
I am trying to call the member function from another member function but
the compiler thinks I am trying to call the C function in the global scope.

I tried the following

```
//header
    namespace myNameSpace{
      class B : public A{
       int read();
       int do_read();
    } 
    }

//cpp
using namespace myNameSpace;
int B::read(){
//other code needed 
_io_read();
}

int B::do_read(){
 this.read(); // here is where compiler resolves to _io_read
}
```

Is there away around this? I rather not rename the base class A's read function because I cannot change code that is not mine.

TIA

Comment: a `#define` is very different from a "C function in the global scope" so you asked your question in a way that invites misunderstanding.  You ought to edit that.  `#define` applies before all scoping rules.  So whoever used `#define` in the way you showed was writing bad C code that is terrible C++ code.  But if you are stuck with including that badly written .h file, you need to deal with it (maybe with `#undef`)

Comment: This is why `#define` gets a bad name. You need to know about `#undef`.

Comment: Anyone that would attempt to define such a generic term as `read` should be fired.

Comment: there's a reason why I did not specify who made the C library :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
int B::do_read(){
 #undef read
 this.read(); // here is where compiler resolves to _io_read
 #define read _io_read
}
```

Comment: I have added the #undef to the beginning of the .cpp file and it worked. If I need to call the C function, I call it directly as _io_read.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would amend the answer to say: in *your* modules, you can redefine all the offending #defines to something less ambiguous. For example, if the #defined C routines are from libquux, you can edit the quux.h to redefine them:

```
/*#define read _io_read*/
#define quux_read _io_read
```

Alas, you haven't much better macro power with the plain CPP.

Answer (score 0):

I placed this at the beginning of the .cpp file and will remove the namespace as it is no longer needed. Sorry for describing the #define as a global scope, still learning the correct nomenclature :)

```
#ifdef read
#undef read
#endif

int B::read(){
//other code needed 
_io_read(); //call C function directly
}

int B::do_read(){
 this.read(); //no more problem here
}
```